# How to handle submit by press enter in react?

Tags: reactjs

When i click enter **send OTP** button is not working. I used material ui and react-phone-input-2. I tried using id in form that also not working.

```
<form onSubmit={otp_validation} className={Styles.lognform} id="loginform">
  <FormControl>
        <PhoneInput
          className={Styles.phoneinpt}
          fullWidth
          name="phoneNumber"
          type="text"
          country={"ae"}
          enableAreaCodes={true}
          placeholder="Your mobile number"
          inputProps={{
            name: "phone",
            country: "us",
            required: true,
            autoFocus: true,
          }}
          onChange={(e) => setPhone(e)}
          countryCodeEditable={false}
          onlyCountries={["ae"]}
          required
        />
        <h6 style={{ fontSize: "12px", color: " red" }}>{moberr}</h6>
  </FormControl>
    <Button
      type="submit"
      className={Styles.btnStyle}
      variant="contained"
      form="loginform"
    >
      send OTP
    </Button>
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `requestSubmit()`. If you add an `onKeyUp` event to `PhoneInput` it should work.

```
onKeyUp={(e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') e.target.form.requestSubmit();
}}
```

But I am not 100% sure that this will work with the types of components you are using since I have only been able to test it with standard elements like `textarea`.